Backtracking Question - Subsets
Reference to solution: https://neetcode.io/problems/combination-target-sum
My question is,
Why does subset.pop() work? -> for this call, how do we know it is referencing the subset state before the call to left branch (decision to add an element) and not the subset state after the call?
For example, if we start by adding 2 to [], we get [2]. And then we explore the left branch. To explore the right branch, we pop subset so we're back to [] at the root -> but how do we actually know we'll get back to [] after pop  and the call to the left branch not something else?
Bc subset is also a global variable, so wouldn't the call to DFS on left branch potentially add elements to the subset?
